# UnhandledException not called for a secondary thread

Tags: .net-core

I'm using a AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException in a .NET Core application and it works for a secondary thread if I wait for it:

```
var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;

Task.Run(() =>
{
   throw new AbandonedMutexException();
})
.Wait();
```

But the exception handler is not called if I just run a thread and don't wait for it. Is there a way to get notified about a crash in a thread like this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element

Comment: Nobody likes that either, for fire-and-forget threading that fail appropriately do favor ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, doesn't seem to work in .NET Core